# Using @Id on methods

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I would like to annotate a method with Spring Data `@Id` but it only works with fields, despite the fact that the annotation can be used on methods.

Is there a way to use `@Id` on methods too?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.3.0.RELEASE

**EDIT**

Actually I have this interface that will have an instance being created at runtime.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

@Document(indexName = "index", type = "document")
public interface Document {

    @Id
    Integer getId();
}
```

And this repository.

```
public interface DocumentRepository extends ElasticsearchCrudRepository<Document, Integer> {

}
```

Problem is that SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty from spring-data-elasticsearch 1.3.0.RELEASE always look for fields:
 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/1.3.0.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/mapping/SimpleElasticsearchPersistentProperty.java

That way if I create an asbtract class instead and put `@Id` on a field, everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The `@Id` annotation does work on properties, i.e. you can put it on getters, setters or fields. If this does not work something is wrong. Possible reasons are:

- the names don't fit the property conventions
- you are using the wrong `@Id` annotation

It does not work on arbitrary methods because Spring Data wouldn't be able to determine a name for that non-property, which in turn is required for many features.

Comment: I have updated my question. It seems to me that it could be a problem with my version of spring-data-elasticsearch.

Comment: 1. The versions from spring boot and spring data elasticsearch are independent. 2. The version you linked to invokes the superclass first, which should do the correct thing. But I'm not sure how using interfaces  for the entity affects things. I get the feeling this actually should work. Can you create an issue, with a reproducable example?